# Orpheus won't install in Delphi XE8

Tags: delphi, installation, package, delphi-xe8

I'm trying to install the Orpheus library in Delphi XE8. I added the source path to the library path, and successfully compiled the run-time package (`OrpheusDR.dpk`). But when I try to install the design-time package (`OrpheusDD.dpk`) Delphi hangs immediately.

[image]

Is there a workaround (like patching certain files) to get the package installed after all?

---

*PS: SysTools (another TurboPack package) installed without problems*

Comment: Did you try to install it via the [GetIt](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Installing_a_GetIt_Package) IDE tool, which automates all installation steps?